Difference between using "dotnet pack" and "GeneratePackageOnBuild"?
I understand that using dotnet pack is intended for creating NuGet packages, and dotnet publish is intended for creating deployable DLLs/EXEs. However, using the GeneratePackageOnBuild property in the .csproj file also creates a NuGet package from the build when calling publish. So my two questions are:

Is there any reason to specifically call dotnet pack instead of just setting GeneratePackageOnBuild to True?
Is there any downside to using dotnet publish for everything and ignoring the non-package output if not needed?

Context: I am using a plugin architecture and I am using publish to create deployable versions of the plugins. For <reasons> I also want the plugins to be available on our private Azure NuGet feed. Currently I am using GeneratePackageOnBuild and publishing the package that is generated as part of publish and nothing has gone wrong yet.

Instead of running separate dotnet build, dotnet pack, and dotnet publish commands, dotnet publish -p:GeneratePackageOnBuild =true will do all three. The dotnet tool has an embedded msbuild. Several of the dotnet sub-commands map to invoking the embedded msbuild for specific targets, e.g. dotnet build is msbuild -t:build. The pack and publish targets will both first try to build. The GeneratePackageOnBuild property adds the pack target after a build target.

@JonathanDodds Yeah, currently I am just running dotnet publish with GeneratePackageOnBuild and knew that it all called msbuild. I wasn't sure if there was anything else "missing" by not calling pack explicitly.

I believe that the NuGet pack target is the same regardless of how it is invoked.


Is there any reason to specifically call dotnet pack instead of just setting GeneratePackageOnBuild to True?

Speed. During development and testing you'll probably be doing many builds. Packing every build is an unnecessary step if a package is not needed.

Is there any downside to using dotnet publish for everything and ignoring the non-package output if not needed?

If you just need the package why do you need publish? Publish could create the package for you as a byproduct but why not use the right tool for the job and avoid unnecessary work?

In my context there are only a few instances where I "just need the package" and so it simplifies our Azure pipeline to just call publish on everything. The speed difference is tiny so I don't think that matters (for ME at least). Probably has a bigger impact for other people's context though.
